# Adding Hyperlinks to Image & Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner coder and I've been tasked to do some coding in JavaScript using the jQuery library.

What I'm supposed to do are two things.

1. When I click on a pre-existing image it redirects me to a URL.
2. When I click a pre-existing text in the navigation bar, it redirects me to a URL.

I can do this fine in HTML but have some challenges with jQuery. Can any kind soul show me where I should start?

Comment: Can you post some code that you have written so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: you need to try out something before posting here, post your tried piece of code..

Comment: Please show us some code and the problems you are facing. It won't help you if the code magically appears.

Answer (score 0):

This info should help you out...

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_end_value.asp